# NGINX Proxy_pass : use proxy_host as the request header host

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to proxy_pass to a website, But I want the request header host to be the same as the website I passed.

I have tried to use "proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host" (and tried change the value to $host, even the exact hostname I want. But when I use google chrome to check the request host, it is still the server IP that I used to set up the proxy_pass.

Below is my config, please help

```
location / {
proxy_pass https://example.com;
proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you are proxying to Apache, then Apache will see this as an HTTP/1.0 request from nginx.  There is a module `mod_rpaf` which allows you to cause Apache to see this the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am proxying to a website that hosted by nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Check the examples from the docs:

nginx first decides which server should process the request. Let’s start with a simple configuration where all three virtual servers listen on port *:80:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    ...
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;
    ...
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

In this configuration, nginx tests only the request’s header field `Host` to determine which server the request should be routed to. If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default server for this port. In the configuration above, **the default server is the first one** — which is nginx’s standard default behaviour. It can also be set explicitly which server should be default, with the default_server parameter in the listen directive:

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;
    ...
}
```

Now keep in mind that `$host` is specifically the first `server_name` that is defined in the current server block. if you have multiple `server_name`'s, only the first one will appear, but if want your backend to receive a fixed `host` name, use:

```
proxy_set_header Host "your.fixed.hostname";
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I got the default host name from my domain (actually I used IP here) . And I tried to use the config (`proxy_set_header Host "your.fixed.hostname";`) to change the `host` name which doesn't work. It still shows the original host name and nothing changed